# Reactjs Filtering a huge array of objects best practices

Tags: arrays, reactjs, design-patterns, filter, redux

in a given app, lets say i have an array that hold 100,000+ object.

objects look like following

```
let collection = [{
  name:'name',
  price: 10,
  group_id: 1
},
{
  name:'name 2',
  price: 8,
  group_id: 2
},
];
```

now lets say i have a view which show all 100,000 object, and allow users to filter list by price range or group_id.

--given that such list can be a static list loaded from remote json, or a redux saved collection.

what is best method to filter this filters using price & group filters ?

my first thinking was to keep another array called "filtered_list" in the state of parent component, and when ever a filter change, the filtered_list will reconstruct by filtering parent Collection (looping 100,000+ object again).

but this look not so performant, so i consider may be i should write some logic that decied if the new filter should use the already `filtered_list` or use parent `collection`

example :- if group_filter was group_id = 1, then a price filter was added then i should filter only filtered_list, since all inputs of group_1 is already in filtered_list, otherwise if group_id changed from 1 -> 2, then i must refilter the whole big collection, because filtered_list doesnot contain group_id =2 items, its on collection only...

this bring me to another problem.. where should i maintain the filtered_list variable ?

if i added it to redux store, this violate princible of redux that store should only hold information needed to build data, and not calculated data.

```
const App = props =><div>
<aside>
 <Filtes />
</aside>
<article>
  {props.collection.map(item=><label>item.name</label>)}
</article>
</div>

export default connect( ({collection})=>({collection}) )(App)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the reselect library which is recommended in the Redux docs for computing derived data:

> Reselect is a simple library for creating memoized, composable
>   selector functions. Reselect selectors can be used to efficiently
>   compute derived data from the Redux store.

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

So you could have a selector that looked something like this:

```
const getGroupdId= state => state.selectedGroupId
const getIteams = state => state.collection

const getVisibleItems= createSelector(
  [getItems, getGroupId],
  (items, groupId) =>
    items.filter(i=> i.group_id === groupId)
)
```

Since the selector is memoized, it will only be recomputed when the selected groupId changes.  I've also combined reselect with an ImmutableJS state in the past as well, which in my experience increased performance when querying large data structures.

Comment: how about how to decied if i should select the collection, or filter only visibleItems, how to accomplish something like this  ? i'm trying to avoid filtering the whole collection since its huge list

Comment: Selectors can be composed, so if you have a selector that filters by group, which is then fed in to a selector that filters by price, if the user changes the price filter, the group filter won't be recalculated https://github.com/reactjs/reselect#composing-selectors